# JavaFx stage.close() not working

Tags: java

```
@Override 
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {  

playerIsSelected = false;
enemyIsSelected = false;
```

---

> Blockquote Can be compiled, but when I click the EXIT button, it shows that the error as: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException.And the Exit button click doesn't exit the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nowhere in your code that the identifier `stage` is defined. However, since your code is compiling I would assume this is defined outside of the method. Though, considering you've invoked `primaryStage.show();`  then eventually you might want to perform  `primaryStage.close();`.

change this:

```
public void exit(){
   stage.close(); //<-- cause of the NullPointerException
}
```

to this:

```
public void exit(){
   primaryStage.close();
}
```

Comment: I actually added "stage = primaryStage" in start method and it was solved; thanks a lot